# Sending parameters to java via c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

My java class has a static function defined as follows:

```
public static void logEvent(final String eventName, final String jObject) {
        //Function data
    }
```

Now my cpp file has the following function

```
void PingoScreen::callApslarIntegration(){
    char* eventName="bingo";
    JniMethodInfo t;  

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, "com/myapp/test/ApslarSetup","logEvent", "()V")) {
    t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
    t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
  }
}
```

How can i send two string params to the JAVA function via JNI  ?

Kind Regards

===============================================================

```
void PingoScreen::callApsIntegration() {

    JniMethodInfo t;

    if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, "com/myapp/test/ApslarSetup",
            "logJSONEvent", "()V")) {

        const char* cstr1 = "Test1";
        const char* cstr2 = "Test2";

        jstring jstr1 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr1);
        jstring jstr2 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr2);

        t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID,jstr1,jstr2);
        t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
    }
}
```

The above function causes a crash ?

==================================

Finally got it to work

```
void PingoScreen::callApslarIntegration() {
    JniMethodInfo t;
    if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo
                (t, "com/nbs/test/ApslarSetup",
                "logJSONEvent",
                "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V")) {

        const char* cstr1 = "Test1";
        const char* cstr2 = "Test2";

        jstring jstr1 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr1);
        jstring jstr2 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr2);

        t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID,jstr1,jstr2);
        t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
    }
}
```

The crash was due to the line

```
if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo
                    (t, "com/nbs/test/ApslarSetup",
                    "logJSONEvent",
                    "(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V"))
```

The signiture had to be `Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;` and not `Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String` (notice the last semi-colon)

Comment: Tip: Use `javap -s -public com.nbs.test.ApslarSetup | egrep -A 2 "logJSONEvent"` to obtain signatures to use with JNI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `CallStaticVoidMethod`, simply pass two `jstring`s to it, like so:

```
const char* cstr1 = "Test1";
const char* cstr2 = "Test2";
jstring jstr1 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr1);
jstring jstr2 = t.env->NewStringUTF(cstr2);
t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID, jstr1, jstr2);
```

You can also use `CallStaticVoidMethodA` or `CallStaticVoidMethodV` instead of simply `CallStaticVoidMethod`. See the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp4796).

Comment: I have edited my question with the updated function. Its causing a crash ?

Comment: Any error log? I'm not by a PC to test it. If the problem is in what I wrote, it's how I'm creating the jstrings, so you may find something quicker by Googling...

Comment: Just a C stack strace that does not seem discernible to me ?

Comment: @Dave- Thank you for your help. The problem was in my code. Thank you for your time.